# How to find a memory leak in a web application running in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, memory-leaks

I've written a web app which after a while causes IE 8's memory usage to soar to just under a Gig. I think there is a memory leak somewhere in the javascript, but I've got no idea how to find the root cause of this.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I make use of intervals to call ajax methods on a Java backend and I'm using Prototype as a JS library...

Comment: For IE6/IE7 there is a plugin you could use http://blogs.msdn.com/gpde/pages/javascript-memory-leak-detector.aspx If the leaks happen there too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Drip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ieleak) and IE Sieve leak detectors help web developers improve the performance of dynamic web pages by reporting avoidable memory leaks caused by Internet Explorer limitations.

try this [JavaScript Memory Leak Detector](http://blogs.msdn.com/gpde/pages/javascript-memory-leak-detector.aspx)